# Does a C# app track how long its been running?

Tags: c#, .net

And if it does, is there an easy way to get the total time since it started?

Comment: Your app or another app? I believe WMI may track something like this, but if it's your own app, it's much simpler to just get the date on startup.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

The `System.Diagnostics.Process` class has a property containing the start time which you can use to calculate how long it has been running:

```
var current = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
DateTime startedAt = current.StartTime
```

Comment: Be aware that `current.StartTime` is server's local time, not UTC.

Comment: `current.StartTime.ToUniversalTime()`

Answer (score 33):

Use `StopWatch` class for this feature.

Even if quite overkill, it will always work, even if the user changes the clock or even if there is some daylight saving changes during the process. -  [Julien Lebosquain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183367/julien-lebosquain) (Comment to my answer.)

Comment: Even if quite overkill, that's the only answer that will always work, even if the user changes the clock, even if there is some daylight saving changes during the process run so +1.

Comment: @JulienLebosquain: Thanks. I will add that point in my answer with due credits.

Answer (score 6):

You can Have a `Static DateTime Variable` for your Project, and store the datetime in the Constructor of your Main Class. Referencing this Static Variable, and comparing with current time helps you achieve your result

Comment: ;) yeah, you can also jsut read out the time from the existing variable ;)